# How do I turn on data binding?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I have seen [this code in one of Google's Android examples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-databinding/todoapp/app/src/main/res/layout/statistics_frag.xml). Code example here:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="stats"
            type="com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.todoapp.statistics.StatisticsViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            <!-- look at this -->
            android:text="@{stats.status}"
            android:visibility="@{stats.showStatus ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

I wanted to use something like this for my own project but it did not compile. I suppose that it requires some libraries or something else but I could not find it. Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

enable `dataBinding` in your `build.gradle`

```
android{
    ...
    ...
    defaultConfig{
        ...
        ...
        dataBinding{
            enabled true
        }
    }
}
```